# selectize.js multi drop down input location

Tags: jquery, css, selectize.js

I am attempting to have the search input as the first element in the multi selectize div. I have tried by manipulating the DOM, and also with CSS only.

I can get the input to be shown first, with the selected options underneath, but this seems to break the functionality of removing tags and I have to click each twice.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let selectize = $("#mySelect").selectize({
    searchField: ["text", "value"],
    plugins: ["remove_button"]
  });
});
```

```css
.selectize-input {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.selectize-input>div {
  order: 2;
}

.selectize-input>input {
  order: 1;
}

.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input>div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

.selectize-control.single .selectize-input::after {
  right: 5px !important;
}

.selectize-control.plugin-remove_button .item {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.bootstrap4.min.css" integrity="sha512-MMojOrCQrqLg4Iarid2YMYyZ7pzjPeXKRvhW9nZqLo6kPBBTuvNET9DBVWptAo/Q20Fy11EIHM5ig4WlIrJfQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.min.css" integrity="sha512-bkB9w//jjNUnYbUpATZQCJu2khobZXvLP5GZ8jhltg7P/dghIrTaSJ7B/zdlBUT0W/LXGZ7FfCIqNvXjWKqCYA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha512-pF+DNRwavWMukUv/LyzDyDMn8U2uvqYQdJN0Zvilr6DDo/56xPDZdDoyPDYZRSL4aOKO/FGKXTpzDyQJ8je8Qw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div style="width:200px;">
  <select id="mySelect" multiple>
    <option value='A'>Value A</option>
    <option value='B'>Value B</option>
    <option value='C'>Value C</option>
    <option value='D'>Value D</option>
    <option value='E'>Value E</option>
    <option value='F'>Value F</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle with my attempt using CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/josborne71/r8h3ze7m/58/

Answer (score 0):

Like it?
https://jsfiddle.net/nhojfv0m/61/

I focused the input and add attr selected on first option.

`selectized[0].selectize.focus();`

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the search input to be above the selected tags. This isn't any different than the default functionality.

Comment: Like it? https://jsfiddle.net/d5c928ye/3/ @JasonO

I insert display flex with column reverse on parent element.

Comment: I tried this but, as stated in the question, this breaks the removing of options in that you have to click each one twice to remove it.